# Android Retrofit NetworkBoundResource returns null

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I am trying to retrieve data from a third-party API using Retrofit and NetworkBoundResource (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide#addendum). However when this NetworkBoundResource runs it returns null.

The JSON I'm trying to fetch is as follows:

```
    {
        "id":93
        "name":"Business"
        "total":587
        "has_next":true
        "podcasts":[]
    }
```

Hoping someone can help! Relevant code below.

**Podcasts.kt**

```
@Keep
@Entity(
    tableName = "podcasts"
)
@Parcelize
data class Podcast(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
    val title: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "publisher")
    val publisher: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "image")
    val image: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "thumbnal")
    val thumbnail: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "url")
    val url: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "total_episodes")
    @Json(name = "total_episodes")
    val total: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "favourite")
    var favourite: Boolean = false,
) : Parcelable

@Entity(
    tableName = "best_podcasts",
    indices = [Index(
        value = ["id"],
        unique = true
    )]
)
data class BestPodcasts(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "podcasts")
    val podcasts: List<Podcast>
)
```

**NetworkBoundResource**

```
    abstract class NetworkBoundResource<ResultType, RequestType>
    @MainThread constructor(private val appExecutors: AppExecutors) {
        //
        private val result = MediatorLiveData<Resource<ResultType>>()

        init {
            result.value = Resource.loading(null)
            @Suppress("LeakingThis")
            val dbSource = loadFromDb()
            result.addSource(dbSource) { data ->
                result.removeSource(dbSource)
                if (shouldFetch(data)) {
                    fetchFromNetwork(dbSource)
                } else {
                    result.addSource(dbSource) { newData ->
                        setValue(Resource.success(newData))
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @MainThread
        private fun setValue(newValue: Resource<ResultType>) {
            if (result.value != newValue) {
                result.value = newValue
            }
        }

        private fun fetchFromNetwork(dbSource: LiveData<ResultType>) {
            val apiResponse = createCall()
            // we re-attach dbSource as a new source, it will dispatch its latest value quickly
            result.addSource(dbSource) { newData ->
                setValue(Resource.loading(newData))
            }
            result.addSource(apiResponse) { response ->
                result.removeSource(apiResponse)
                result.removeSource(dbSource)
                when (response) {
                    is ApiSuccessResponse -> {
                        appExecutors.diskIO().execute {
                            saveCallResult(processResponse(response))
                            appExecutors.mainThread().execute {
                                // we specially request a new live data,
                                // otherwise we will get immediately last cached value,
                                // which may not be updated with latest results received from network.
                                result.addSource(loadFromDb()) { newData ->
                                    setValue(Resource.success(newData))
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    is ApiEmptyResponse -> {
                        appExecutors.mainThread().execute {
                            // reload from disk whatever we had
                            result.addSource(loadFromDb()) { newData ->
                                setValue(Resource.success(newData))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    is ApiErrorResponse -> {
                        onFetchFailed()
                        result.addSource(dbSource) { newData ->
                            setValue(Resource.error(response.errorMessage, newData))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        fun asLiveData() = result as LiveData<Resource<ResultType>>

        @WorkerThread
        protected open fun processResponse(response: ApiSuccessResponse<RequestType>) = response.body

        @WorkerThread
        protected abstract fun saveCallResult(item: RequestType)

        @MainThread
        protected abstract fun shouldFetch(data: ResultType?): Boolean

        @MainThread
        protected abstract fun loadFromDb(): LiveData<ResultType>

        @MainThread
        protected abstract fun createCall(): LiveData<ApiResponse<RequestType>>

        protected open fun onFetchFailed() {
            Log.d("AHHHH", "Fetch failed")
        }
    }
```

**RemoteDataSource**

```
    class RemoteDataSource {
        private val podcastApiService = PodcastApi.retrofitService

        fun downloadBestPodcasts(): LiveData<ApiResponse<BestPodcasts>> {
            return podcastApiService.downloadBestPodcasts()
        }
    }
```

**DataRepository**

```
    class DataRepository(
        private val localDataSource: LocalDataSource,
        private val remoteDataSource: RemoteDataSource,
        private val appExecutors: AppExecutors
    ) {
        fun downloadBestPodcasts(shouldFetch: Boolean): LiveData<Resource<BestPodcasts>> {
            return object :
                NetworkBoundResource<BestPodcasts, BestPodcasts>(appExecutors) {
                override fun saveCallResult(item: BestPodcasts) {
                    localDataSource.insertBestPodcasts(item)
                }

                override fun shouldFetch(data: BestPodcasts?) = data == null || shouldFetch

                override fun loadFromDb(): LiveData<BestPodcasts> =
                    localDataSource.getBestPodcasts()

                override fun createCall() = remoteDataSource.downloadBestPodcasts()
            }.asLiveData()
        }
    }
```

**WebService**

```
    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(LiveDataCallAdapterFactory())
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .build()

    interface WebService {
        @GET("best_podcasts")
        fun downloadBestPodcasts(
            @Header("X-ListenAPI-Key") apiKey: String = BuildConfig.API_KEY,
            @Query("genre") genreId: Int? = null
        ): LiveData<ApiResponse<BestPodcasts>>
    }
```